# Echo is not giving me output

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT cult_desc FROM culture");

while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
    for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
        $csv_output .= $rowr[$j]."; ";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time());
#echo $filename;
echo $csv_output;
```

As far as I can tell, it should go through each piece of data, echo it with a ";" and then a newline. Instead, it gives me no output.

Comment: what's the value of $i? try for ($j=0, $i=count($rowr);$j<$i;$j++). in that case change it to mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: depends what the value of $i is to start with

Comment: Where do you set the value of $i?

Comment: did you try var_dumping $rowr or putting a counter on that while loop to see if your query is even returning anything?

Comment: I assume you know that your SQL query is actually returning data? If not, it *would* output nothing (well, an empty string, assuming $csv_output isn't set to anything else before your code snippet).

Answer (score 1):

From the variable name (`$csv_output`) it seems you need CSV formatted output.

If you have `FILE` privilege why not invoke,

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT cult_desc INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM culture");
readfile("/tmp/result.txt");
```

Otherwise following code will do it.

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT cult_desc FROM culture");
$csv_output = "";
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
    $csv_output .= implode(";", $rowr). "\n";
}
$filename = $file."_".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time());
#echo $filename;
echo $csv_output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `$csv_output` with an empty string so it has something to concatenate onto. Otherwise you may get a notice, and your code won't work. Additionally, check to make sure there are actually values in your results.

`$csv_output = ''` ought to do the trick, call that before your loop unless you initialize it elsewhere.

You also need to replace `$i` with `$j` unless you have `$i` declared elsewhere?

Comment: Just replacing $i with $j doesn't sound too good if there is a for loop "for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++)"...

Answer (score 0):

First of all mysql_fetch_row has in your case just one key its 0 (there the cult_desc field is stored).

You can use your code like this:

```
$csv_output = "";
$values = mysql_query("SELECT cult_desc FROM culture");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) {
    $csv_output .= $rowr['cult_desc']."; \n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time());
#echo $filename;
echo $csv_output;
```

i replaced mysql_fetch_row with mysql_fetch_assoc so you get the field name as the key not a number. With that you can direct access with cult_desc